# Lookup data corresponding to the same time for each date

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2019

I have a sheet with two columns, column A is the date and time and column B is the data:

```
        A        B   
  |------------------------|----|
1 | 7/21/2023  12:00:00 AM | 5  |
  |------------------------|----|
2 | 7/21/2023   6:00:00 AM | 23 |
  |------------------------|----|
3 | 7/21/2023  12:00:00 PM | 18 |
  |------------------------|----|
1 | 7/22/2023  12:00:00 AM | 4  |
  |------------------------|----|
2 | 7/22/2023   6:00:00 AM | 53 |
  |------------------------|----|
3 | 7/22/2023  12:00:00 PM | 10 |
  |------------------------|----|
```

I want to extract the data from column B for 12:00 AM for each day and ignore the other values so I end up with a table like this:

```
        A        B   
  |------------------------|----|
1 | 7/21/2023  12:00:00 AM | 5  |
  |------------------------|----|
2 | 7/22/2023  12:00:00 AM | 4  |
  |------------------------|----|
```

Any ideas how I would do this? Pivot table seems to be an option but I'm not familiar with it enough to make it work. I couldn't get VLOOKUP to do what I need either. Thank you.

Comment: Which programming languages are you familiar with? Have you used VBA before?

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-check-if-time-is-greater-than-or-less-than-a-specific-time-in-excel

Comment: A pivot table won't work, Maybe it could work in power query if you don't aggregate the results. Using the `Filter()` formula with a time function would probably do it. are you certain there will be only one 12:00:00 AM time per day?

Comment: A helper column to extract the time value only might be useful. For example: `=TIME(HOUR(A2),MINUTE(A2),SECOND(A2))` and copy it down. Then you could use AutoFilter on the helper column to filter the data in place, or Advanced Filter to copy the results to another location.

Answer (score 0):

In a new Excel using FILTER function would be appropriate, but without that function you can do it in an old style.
I hope this date and time formats are native in your system. Then you can use formulas:
`=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$6,SMALL(IF(MOD($A$1:$A$6,1)=0,ROW($A$1:$A$6)),ROW(A1))),"")`
for a date in E1 and
`=IF(E1="","",VLOOKUP(E1,$A$1:$B$6,2,FALSE))`
for value in F1.
The TIMEVALUE for midnight ("12:00:00 AM") is 0, that was used in the above formula. If you need another time you can use `=TIMEVALUE(your_time)` instead.
[image: DateTime]

Answer (score 0):

For those using Excel 365, as stated on the comments, one can use the `FILTER` function. Adapt the following formula

```
=FILTER($C$2:$C$7;($A$2:$A$7=F5)*($B$2:$B$7=G5))
```

- `($A$2:$A$7=F5)*($B$2:$B$7=G5)`: this part of the formula performs an `AND` operation to check that the date and time correspond.
- After the check is complete, the corresponding value from column C is shown.

You can englobe the formula with `IFERROR` in case the criteria are not found.

```
=IFERROR(FILTER($C$2:$C$7;($A$2:$A$7=F5)*($B$2:$B$7=G5));0)
```

[image]